# Vega lite line chart add custom x-axes names

Tags: data-visualization, vega-lite, vega

I want my line chart x-axes names contains only odd numbers. I tried 'xLabel' properties but this did not help. Any idea how to do it?

Here is my vega lite [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega/N4IgJgpgzgxgTgSwA4BcEHsB2IBcIAq6KAhgDYAEAwugK6YrmkKYTkwAWxcKAdCADQgA7gjAp2uAIwAmAAyzB7CAgDm7FLgAsAVgUgkxMGGYrc2wVFWYyUXAG1Q1gLYRcIZighwk6UsU8CIABuZDSueEwsXCAAvgC6gqQQKhCYYLY4DiAAZgikpG4wvuhwgSUIqRp4AEZEKOhOgcZwEDBoWG7s5QBeWCQFFgCeTrWk+INI4SBQAI40XK7xgmD+xPaOxC5uJNVJgSGkYRlZAB64eoNSOoIwbgCC+YEnADLE1RAFeLH8oGc4koJLv9tABmG73R6CF5vD5uRY-EB-aSA3DSAAcelueAeA0Rr3enxA31+uDBICBkl04OxkLxMMJphiCL+mhROHRmIhuOhBLcxMRZjZkk0nJp3PxsLw2Wy-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-xAeSEAyZzEB-O8IEEFRsuoEDSjCkEyvK2ImRAfi4AAa2OUBwKmAraCQaK4AaIccmIE8qg2LY8CgLwKlsZYRJAMSP1DDqaCQaogWkyrBBq+qqyatdmCm7IOsaISRzWQbhsrKrUiKSAusqQ0hL+UBYAsvTosk2dviTeydKmZcJOnSyqocjravCW73sKYoPSnb9Chev70AB2LRHELqDjCVFUtmkdAfcegvB8PwAnsqwyDcDxsd8fx4WmM8YYgXUDBgBAG0R0JwkkKr6l8NA2vxlQYLcEcaEaVKuiCK7bspgGaZ6+mgVAJHwlkHhtHnWT4hiIA)

Comment: Can you clarify? You only want 1,3 and 5 to show on the x axis labels?

Comment: You can use the `values` axis parameter to specify exact axis ticks https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html#ticks

Comment: @David yes, this is what I want. I found a solution based on hint from @ joelostblom. Here is an updated [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/cc86eeb91a9a9fe658ecd17846b86ece/spec.json). Huge thanks for both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marked as answered with help from @joelostblom

```
"values": [1, 3, 5]
```